# Is it possible to scrape a webpage by HTML class names?

Tags: java, android, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to scrape, and I only want a few particular classes to be scraped. How do I go about scraping just the classes I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "classes", you mean html elements with a specific `class` attribute, then what you'll do is use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) to scrape, parse, and tidy the whole page, and then [use CSS selectors to grab the elements](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) you're interested in.